# How to get the option value of the select box in the controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller with the index `function()` and I would like to get the selected value of the option value of the view in the controller `index()`.

```
public function index() {
    $this->accesscontrol->can_or_redirect('view', 'translation');
    $this->output->view('translation/language');
}
```

My view is as follows:

```
<select name="lang_choice1" id="lang_choice1">
    <?php
    $path = './application/language/';
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            echo "<option value='" . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "'>".$fileinfo->getFilename()."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please, explain your question, it is not clear.

Comment: well it should be in your $_POST variable is you are posting it.

Comment: @programmer can you tell me which option want to select n where you have that variable?

Comment: Its not directly accessible, you are not given the name attribute too in option. You can use ajax for get the value.

Answer (score 0):

create a form tag with method post and also set action url to your controller
        and also create a button with type submit so that on submitting the form you can get the selected value in the  controller

Answer (score 0):

If you need return any value back to `CONTROLLER` from `VIEW`.

Your need to pass all those values to `url` via `GET` or `POST` request and you can get all the values through `uri` segments.